# EditText is showing empty even if value is entered

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to authenticate user using email and password. I am doing validations but the problem I am using Retrofit library to post data whenever I comment network request code in else block its showing no error nut whenever I am uncomment network  request code its showing error toast message `Enter password` even if I have entered password.

Below is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    pwd = findViewById(R.id.pwd);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog prg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prg.setCancelable(false);
            prg.setMessage("Logging in...");
            prg.show();

            String str1 = email.getText().toString();
            String str2 = pwd.getText().toString();

            if(str1.equals("")){

                prg.dismiss();
                TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter email",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }
            else if(str2.equals("")){

                prg.dismiss();
                TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter password",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
                ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

                apiService.getResponse(str1,str2).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(final LoginResponse value) {

                                if(value.equals("Success")){

                                    prg.dismiss();

                                }

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"response:" +value,TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                                TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                prg.dismiss();

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter password",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                                TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                            }
                        });
                 }
            });
         }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have kept an `Enter password` Toast in onError of retrofit call  it might be something like `Something Went Wrong ` So basically the request is failing

Comment: Yeah bro there was an error in api request, thanks for a catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1.equals("")
```

return the boolean result if the str1 (String) object equals the String obj= "", in this case, it is preferable to use

```
if(str1.isEmpty())
```

this return if the str1 is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this for better code:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str1))
```